# Prototype: Form.serialize missing some inputs (due to table?)

Tags: ajax, forms, html-table, prototypejs

I'm using JavaScript Prototype (through Ruby on Rails) to handle some Ajax calls; but in one particular case I'm missing a field from the form.

I have a layout like this:

```
+---------+---------+
| Thing 1 | Thing 2 |
+---------+---------+-----------+
| o Opt 1 | o Opt 1 | <Confirm> |
| o Opt 2 | o Opt 2 |           |
+---------+---------+-----------+
```

Opt 1 and 2 are Radio buttons, Confirm is a button. The entire table is wrapped in a form, with code like:

```
<form action="javascript:void(0)">
  <input type="hidden" name="context" value="foo" />
  <input type="hidden" name="subcontext" value="bar" />
  <table>
    <tr><td>Thing 1</td><td>Thing2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>
      <input type="radio" name="choice" value="1.1" />Opt 1<br />
      <input type="radio" name="choice" value="1.2" />Opt 2<br />
    </td><td>
      <input type="radio" name="choice" value="2.1" />Opt 1<br />
      <input type="radio" name="choice" value="2.2" />Opt 2<br />
    </td><td>
      <input name="choice_btn" type="button" value="Confirm"
             onclick="new AJAX.Updater('my_form', '/process_form',
                      {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true,
                       parameters:Form.serialize(this.form)});
                       return false;" />
    </td></tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

But I can see that the POST generated by clicking the Confirm button contains the `foo` and `bar` values for the hidden fields, but not the choice of the radio buttons.

Is this because I've got a table inside my form? How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, which isn't evident from the pasted code above. Before the AJAX request is built, the onclick handler is disabling a number of form objects, including the radio buttons and the  button itself. If I move those steps to the AJAX `onLading` parameter, it all gets sent.